# Ember-data model issue: weird request URL

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, amd

I'm trying to build a simple ember application (filebrowser) using an AMD approach (yes i know about @tomdale's views on AMD) based on https://github.com/fernandogmar/Emberjs-RequireJS, which seems to work nicely except I'm getting a weird request URL when trying to use this DS.Model:

```
App.File = DS.Model.extend({
    primaryKey: "URI",

    url: "file",

    URI: DS.attr("string")
});
```

Called with:

```
window.App.DataStore.find(File, encodeURIComponent("/"));
```

(Unrelated question: is there any way to get the datastore from within a router or controller with get()? `Router.get("DataStore")` returns undefined.)

Using the standard unmodified RESTAdapter. Results in the following request URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8020/model)s/%2F
```

I can't figure out what causes this. Presumable the 's' at the end is the adapter trying to pluralize the model name. I don't have a clue where the paren comes from.

Ember version: v1.0.0-pre.2-123-ga352c48

Ember-data version: latest downloaded from https://github.com/emberjs/data/downloads yesterday (can't find a version number anywhere).

Could this be related to the AMD approach or is this an unrelated issue, and most importantly: how do i fix it?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using `File.reopenClass()` to set the url property instead of setting it in `extend()` does fix the problem. This doesn't explain why the default magic for generating the modelname returns `model)s`, but atleast it fixes my problem for now.